# Enzyme setup error: "Jest encountered an unexpected token"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, enzyme, react-16

I have a problem setting up enzyme on a project using react-16 as front-end

I've got this error when I try to test

[image]

Here is my **package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "react-dates": "^21.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0",
    "react-toolbox": "^2.0.0-beta.13",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
  }
```

Test config file **test.config.json**

```
{
    "testRegex": "((\\.|/*.)(test))\\.js?$",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
        "<rootDir>/app/resources/js/test/setupTests.js"
    ]
}
```

Setut test config file **setupTests.js**

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({
    adapter: new Adapter()
});
```

Comment: Have you tried destructuring configure? I don't think it's in the default export

Comment: Yes I tried same error, I think the problem is on one of the package but I don't really know which one

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I reinstalled this packages

```
npm install @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

For testing I used **PhpStorm** so I had to add config file into the **Jest options**